# How to upload Maven packages and build info to Artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm a little confused about how this should work.

I have a Jfrog Maven repo. In my Jenkins pipeline I'm just using `mvn deploy` to deploy to it.

But I want to get build info too.

There is a Jenkins plugin you access in a pipeline like this:

```
def artifactory = Artifactory.server 'my-jfrog.jfrog.io'
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
```

But then there is also a Maven specific thing: `def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()`

It looks like if you use `newMavenBuild()` it runs mvn for you? I don't want that. I'd like to run my own mvn commands but also add Jfrog build info for those package deploys - is this possible? Can I run `mvn` myself and also create build info for those?

Comment: Are you missing the Maven Artifactory Plugin https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin ?

Comment: 1. `rtMaven.run()` runs mvn for you.
2. Why wouldn't you want that the plugin run mvn for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here are list of buildinfo's

```
def artifactory = Artifactory.server 'my-jfrog.jfrog.io'
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
def rtGradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
def rtNpm = Artifactory.newNpmBuild()
def conanClient = Artifactory.newConanClient()
def rtDocker = Artifactory.docker server: server, host: "tcp://<daemon IP>:<daemon port>"
```

def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild() it will create a maven repository and will download  all your artifacts from maven automatically and will upload all your artifacts to your artifactory

Please find more information at below doc 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax

Comment: Sorry, but this is not true. This OOP syntax only creates objects within the scripted pipeline. It doesn't create maven repositories. To run maven build you need to invoke `rtMaven.run`